# can i have unique constrain on a NULLable fields?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following scehma

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable  
(  
  ID                INTEGER DEFAULT(1,1),  
  FirstIdentifier   INTEGER NULL,  
  SecondIdentifier  INTEGER NULL,  
--.... some other fields .....  
)
```

Now each of FirstIdentifier &  SecondIdentifier isunique but NULLable. I want to put a unique constraint on each of this column but cannot do it because its NULLable and can have two rows with NULL values that will fail that unique constraints. Any ideas of how can I address it on schema level?

Comment: Add some triggers to catch inserts/updates and do the uniqueness checks at that level?

Comment: How about making FirstIdentifier and Secondidentifier composite key?

Comment: Are you trying to create `Candidate Key {FirstIdentifier , SecondIdentifier}` or `Candidate Key1 {FirstIdentifier}`, `Candidate Key2{SecondIdentifier}`

Comment: Could you be a little more specific regarding the situation as it is right now, and what you want to achieve. I see that the schema is NOT NULL (so, it's not NULLable) so the unique constraint should work find on the schema as it is right now.

Comment: @Conrad: I am thinking about Candidate Key1 {FirstIdentifier}, Candidate Key2{SecondIdentifier}

Comment: @Garuda: Sorry those were actually NULLable, fixed in the question above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a filtered index as a unique constraint.

```
create unique index ix_FirstIdentifier on MyTable(FirstIdentifier) 
  where FirstIdentifier is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

As several have suggested, using a filtered indexe is probably the way to get what you want.

But the book answer to your direct question is that a column can be nullable if it has a unique index, but it will only be able to have one row with a null value in that field.  Any more than one null would violate the index.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing. First, in your schema definition, you say that your columns are not allowed to hold null values, but in your description, you say that they can be null.

Anyway, assuming you've got the schema wrong, and you actually wanted the columns to allow null values, SQL Server allows you to do this by adding WHERE  IS NOT NULL to the constraint.

Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_my_index
ON MyTable (firstIdentifier)
WHERE firstIdentifier IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a filtered unique index on the fields:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_IndexName ON MyTable (FirstIdentifier, SecondIdentifier)
   WHERE FirstIdentifier IS NOT NULL
   AND SecondIdentifier IS NOT NULL
```

It will allow `NULL` but still enforce uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter predicate on the CREATE INDEX

From [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

> CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name 
>  
>          ON  ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) 
>  
>         [ INCLUDE ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
>  
>      **[ WHERE `<filter_predicate>` ]** 
>  
>       [ WITH (  [ ,...n ] ) ] 
>  
>        [ ON { partition_scheme_name ( column_name ) 
>  
>            | filegroup_name 
>  
>            | default 
>  
>            }
>  
>       ]
>  
>       [ FILESTREAM_ON { filestream_filegroup_name |
>   partition_scheme_name | "NULL" } ]
>   
>   [ ; ]
>
> WHERE `<filter_predicate>` Creates a filtered index by specifying which
>   rows to include in the index. The filtered index must be a
>   nonclustered index on a table. Creates filtered statistics for the
>   data rows in the filtered index.
>
> The filter predicate uses simple comparison logic and cannot reference
>   a computed column, a UDT column, a spatial data type column, or a
>   hierarchyID data type column. Comparisons using NULL literals are not
>   allowed with the comparison operators. Use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL
>   operators instead.
>
> Here are some examples of filter predicates for the
>   Production.BillOfMaterials table:
>
> WHERE StartDate > '20040101' AND EndDate <= '20040630'
>
> WHERE ComponentID IN (533, 324, 753)
>
> WHERE StartDate IN ('20040404', '20040905') AND EndDate IS NOT NULL
>
> Filtered indexes do not apply to XML indexes and full-text indexes.
>   For UNIQUE indexes, only the selected rows must have unique index
>   values. Filtered indexes do not allow the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option.